# Wordpress CSS/Theme gone after SSL got activated

Tags: redirect, ssl, https

I can just see the skeleton of my site. I cleared the cache on cloudflare, what else can i do?

Even domain.com/wp-admin login screen is messed up, which means it probably has something to do with godaddy. I don't have experience with this though, can you point me in right direction?

I am getting this error message: Mixed Content: The page at ...... was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script.

Solution: Install Really Simple SSL plugin (for any people in future having same problem)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you switched over to HTTPS and your site assets aren't loading.  Here are a few things you can try.

- Update your site address by going to `Admin > Settings > General` and making sure you have https instead of just http in the URL fields
- Add `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);` to `wp-config.php`
- Change any static links in the content to use https
- Update your .htaccess file to something similar to the below code

  ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
   </IfModule>
  ```

I would start with the first one, do it and then check the site before moving onto the next one.  Then continue down the list.

Comment: I'd also use a Search/Replace plugin to change http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com . This will ensure media files have the right URL. And it may be that your theme is causing the problem. Use the browser's Inspector to see what is being requested as non-ssl.

Comment: This works BUT...  I found this question because it did not initially work for me.  I had done everything RiddleMethis suggested, but no luck.  This solution works if you put the mod_rewrite code *FIRST* in your .htaccess file.  A typical WP site has WP, cache, and Wordfence directives in the .htaccess file.  They seem to process from start to finish, so the switch to SSL needs to be first in the .htaccess file.